# use iOS data model and import it into SQLite for Android

Tags: android, database, android-sqlite

I got iOS data model, consisting of 16 Entities (Tables i guess). So, as I'm doing Android version of this app, I'd need to or import this model somehow automatically (preferred way), or I need to create SQL queries in order to do that.

Now, that is 16 tables that later need to be replicated with web service, so I'd like to keep database exact as is.

What would be the best approach to this problem, and where to put database creation, as in original database some preferences that are used on application load are within "settings" table in that particular database.

Tnx

Edit 1: XML Model from iOS first two tables:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<model name="" userDefinedModelVersionIdentifier="" type="com.apple.IDECoreDataModeler.DataModel" documentVersion="1.0" lastSavedToolsVersion="1487" systemVersion="11E53" minimumToolsVersion="Xcode 4.1" macOSVersion="Automatic" iOSVersion="Automatic">
<entity name="FAQItem" representedClassName="FAQItem" syncable="YES">
<attribute name="answer" attributeType="String" syncable="YES"/>
<attribute name="orderNum" attributeType="Integer 16" defaultValueString="0" syncable="YES"/>
<attribute name="question" attributeType="String" syncable="YES"/>
</entity>
<entity name="Ingredient" representedClassName="Ingredient" syncable="YES">
<attribute name="name" optional="YES" attributeType="String" syncable="YES"/>
<relationship name="recipe" optional="YES" minCount="1" maxCount="1" deletionRule="Nullify" destinationEntity="Recipe" inverseName="ingredients" inverseEntity="Recipe" syncable="YES"/>
</entity>
```

Comment: there is no automatic approach I know of. Using [ormlite](http://ormlite.com/sqlite_java_android_orm.shtml) is probably the closest to to the IOS data model

Comment: the iOS datamodel IS a sqlite database, you should be able to find it somewhere in your emulator (or device) working folders for your app.

Comment: mihail, I got .xml from iOS developer. I Do not have iOS emulator, nor have clue how to do anything with iOS and Xcode :) So, I have .xml vhere I see entities, and should import that into SQLite for Android. Tnx!

Comment: I guess this xml is some kind of definition of the data model. You should make the correct type mapping on your own. As zapl said, there is no automatic approach. Or you can ask the developer to send you the sqlite database from the iOS emulator/device.

Comment: Maybe you could post the XML here? Or a dummy xml with the same format? Android can parse XML so it must be possible.

Comment: Yep, xml is definition of data model, as iOS works with inbuilt ORM if I got it right, but I might be telling stupid things, as I never developed a line for iOS. I can't post the XML unfortunately but I'll do some dummy one and edit the post.

Comment: Ok, I got .sqlite file from iOS developer. What now. 

There are MetaData and Primary key tables that iOS ORM creates, i guess I should remove it, rename fields, and then import it somehow, or use it somehow through ormlite ...

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do that is to write a script who parse the xml datas, and generates java class files. Its not impossible, but a little complicated. But i think this can be a very good idea!